# Differences between mounting networkshares via mount vs. via fstab

Tags: linux, mount

I'm sort of stuck here. I searched the net for answers, to no avail.

I just set up a GIGABYTE Brix with Arch Linux, everything works as expected.

Now I want to set up network shares at boot time. After fixing some problems I now am left with a hurdle I cannot master:

I have two shares on a Qnap TS-469-1 which I can connect to via the command line, yet using fstab only one of them is mounted, while the other one is not.

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.178.40/Download /mnt/qnap/Download -o username=myuser,password=mypass,iocharset=utf8,vers=2.0

mount -t cifs //192.168.178.40/Backup /mnt/qnap/Backup -o username=myuser,password=mypass,iocharset=utf8,vers=2.0
```

These commands will mount both of them, while fstab

```
//192.168.178.40/Download /mnt/qnap/Download cifs noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev,username=myuser,password=mypass,iocharset=utf8,vers=2.0  0  0
//192.168.178.40/Backup /mnt/qnap/Backup cifs noauto,x-systemd.automount;_netdev,username=myuser,password=mypass,iocharset=utf8,vers=2.0  0  0
```

does mount only the first one (Download)

On the Qnap (Server) uname -a gives

```
Linux TS-469-1 3.4.6 #1 SMP Thu Apr 19 05:28:33 CST 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

smbd -V gives

```
Version 4.4.16
```

On the GIGABYTE (client) uname -a gives

```
Linux GIGABYTE 4.16.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Apr 26 16:53:40 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

smbd -V gives

```
Version 4.8.0
```

Any help appreciated !

P.S. after removing the "noauto" parameter from the fstab lines it works. Not sure where that cam from, according to man fstab it is prohibiting automounts.

Still the question remains, why some shares got mounted, while others on the same server did not.

Puzzled.

Comment: How do you check whether it is mounted? What are you expecting from `x-systemd.automount`?

Comment: I simply ls the mountpoint. E.g. ls /mnt/qnap/xyz. The x-systemd.automount should ensure that mounting takes place _after_ the network is up-

Answer (score 2):

There's a syntax error in your 2nd entry, resulting in these being parsed as one unknown option:

```
x-systemd.automount;_netdev
```